# MVC - Is it possible to call an actionResult function from another ActionResult function when return views are different

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a class **SuperMapModel**

```
public class SuperMapModel
{
    public StudentAssessmentViewModel saVM { get; set; }
    public SearchControlViewModel scM { get; set; }
}
```

On my page About.cshtml Markup is

```
@model SuperMapModel

<div>
@Html.Partial("_SearchPanel", Model.scM)
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 table-responsive" id="mapsDiv">
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Maps/_MapDetailsList.cshtml", Model.saVM)

</div>
```

From my **HomeController** i am setting both the above properties and returning the model as follows

```
 public ActionResult About()
 { 
       SuperMapModel smM = new SuperMapModel();
       smM.scM = new SearchControlViewModel();
        smM.scM.x = ..
        smM.scM.y = ..

        smM.saVM = new StudentAssessmentViewModel();
        smM.saVM.x = ..
        smM.saVM..y = ..
        smM.saVM..z = ..

        return View(smM);
 }
```

Now when the page is reloaded i only refresh partial view _MapDetailsList.cshtml in the page through ajax. So i call another function in MapsController (from javascript ) which does almost the same thing as above

```
public ActionResult DisplaySearchResults(int mapHeaderId, int yearId, string classIds, int indicatorGroup, string indicatorIds)
{
       SuperMapModel smM = new SuperMapModel();
        smM.saVM = new StudentAssessmentViewModel();

       smM.saVM.x = ..
        smM.saVM..y = ..
        smM.saVM..z = ..
        return PartialView("~/Views/Maps/_MapDetailsList.cshtml", smM.saVM);
}
```

Is it possible that i can call DisplaySearchResults from within About() for refactoring purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a third method and call it from the others.

```
void PopulateStudentAssessmentViewModel(SuperMapModel smM) {
    smM.saVM = new StudentAssessmentViewModel();

    smM.saVM.x = ..
    smM.saVM..y = ..
    smM.saVM..z = ..
}
```

Comment: although this is the obivous solution i was looking for something like RedirectToAction available in aspnet mvc